# How do I make P4V set the Perforce environment variables?

Tags: perforce, p4v, p4win

**`P4WIN`** has a menu item `use current as default` which sets the currently selected perforce connection to the Windows environment variables. I'd like to get the same functionality out of **`P4V`**, but I haven't been able to locate the option. Does anyone know where to find this, or how to add this functionality?

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/631443/fix-p4-command-line-to-always-work) has a work around for the command line, but I'd like to do the same thing from the GUI.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to do this from the GUI? Isn't the workaround that you linked to adequate?

Comment: The reason I want to do it automatically from the GUI is because I want to use the GUI to manage a number of different perforce connections and I don't want to have to create a new shell script every time I add a new perforce connection to my P4V client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In P4V

1. Connection->Environment Settings...
2. Check "Use current connection for environment settings".

This works well when you have the following settings:

1. Edit->Preferences...
2. Connections
3. "When the application launches:", set to "Open the connection specified by your Perforce environment settings"

Comment: This doesn't seem to set the environment variables on my machine. I can check by opening a terminal (`cmd`) and typing `SET`. The response is no P4 environment variables in the list at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @cordoro, this sets the p4 environment variables (just like the old p4win command did), not the Windows environment variables.  At the command line, type `p4 set` to verify.

Comment: Perfect, that did it. I think it was the second part that I needed, because I had the "Use current connection for environment settings" checked before and it wasn't working.

Comment: I am having trouble making the environment follow the workspace currently selected in P4V. Am having to uncheck, re-check and close the environment dialog for P4 to reflect the new selection. Could be an old bug as we are using the 2012 version - oops server is 2012, my P4V is actually even older. What version are you using?

Comment: @MarjanVenema My P4V version is 2012. It seems to work once I configure both of the above settings.

Comment: @cordoro: thanks. I have since upgraded to 2014.1 and still have to open and close the environment settings dialog before P4 sees that I have changed workspaces in P4V. :( Ah well, will talk to Perforce about it.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows go to Connection > Environment Settings... and click the checkbox at the bottom to set your current values in the environment. This menu option only appears on Windows.

Comment: Is it the `Configure Sandbox...` or `Switch to Workspace...`? Neither of those sound like the right thing, but they are about 2/3 of the way down.